# Reduce memory consumed by method that uses OpenCv on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimization, opencv, image-processing

I am using [OpenCV on iOS](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/table_of_content_ios/table_of_content_ios.html) to do some image processing on a `UIImage`.

The method `processImage` is consuming too much memory. When I profile the App with allocations in Instruments. The `Live Bytes` peaks at `65MB` to `70MB` for about a second. This causes the application to crash.

It used to be higher i.e. `~90MB`, changing `int ddepth` reduced this ( from `CV_16S` to `CV_8U`). While I do understand that reducing the 'desired depth of the destination image' may reduce the memory consumed, I do not understand it's inner workings to pick the best
format.

The reduction in `ddepth` also seems to increase the execution time of the method.

I wish to greatly reduce the `Live Bytes` peak and reduce the execution time of the method as well .

Any insights in how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)processImage:(UIImage *)imageToProcess
{
cv::Mat imageMatrix;

double  sigmaX = 1.0;

int ddepth = CV_8U; //  ddepth – The desired depth of the destination image

cv::GaussianBlur( [self cvMatFromUIImage:imageToProcess], imageMatrix, cv::Size(3,3), sigmaX);

cv::Laplacian(imageMatrix, imageMatrix, ddepth, 1);

double minVal;
double maxVal;

cv::minMaxLoc(imageMatrix, &minVal, &maxVal);

std::cout << "min val : " << minVal << std::endl;
std::cout << "max val: " << maxVal << std::endl;

}
```

Edit Note : I am using [cvMatFromUIImage](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html#opencviosimagemanipulation) from `docs.opencv.org`

Edit Update : I accepted @sansuiso 's answer as it reduced the `Live Bytes` by `~3MB`.
However, I am still looking for further reduction, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the definition of your `cvMatFromUIImage:` method?

Comment: @BenLings [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html#opencviosimagemanipulation) it is from docs.opencv.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `cv::GaussianBlur` can process an image in-place.
You can assign the output of `[self cvMatFromUIImage:imageToProcess]` to your variable `imageMatrix`, which will avoid an extra image creation and reduce the peak value, i.e., proceed with:

```
cv::Mat imageMatrix = `[self cvMatFromUIImage:imageToProcess];
cv::GaussianBlur(imageMatrix, imageMatrix, cv::Size(3,3), sigmax);
```

You may also want to check the content of the `cvMatFromUIImage` method to ensure that everything is released correctly inside.

Comment: Thanks @sansuiso, I'm sorry I do not follow exactly what you mean regarding 'You can assign the output of [self cvMatFromUIImage:imageToProcess]'.

Comment: i.e. `cv::Mat imageMatrix = [self cvMatFromUIImage:imageToProcess];`
 then 
    `cv::GaussianBlur( imageMatrix, imageMatrix, cv::Size(3,3), sigmaX);` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's either memory leak in the `[self cvMatFromUIImage:]` or **often memory allocation problem**.

To be sure there is no memory leak please show us `cvMatFromUIImage` listing.

**Memory allocation**

Try moving all your temporary images to class members. This eliminate unnecessary memory allocations and your code will be reusing allocated memory on each frame. No memory manager likes when user code does constant memory allocations of huge amounts of memory and frees it.
You should try to avoid it because it cause spikes in memory consumptions and crashes because memory manager can hold a free memory in use for some time (after you deallocate cv::Mat).

Comment: [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html#opencviosimagemanipulation) it is from docs.opencv.org.